# How can I add progress bar and update it with QThread?

Tags: qthread, qprogressbar

I want to create a progress bar in my GUI and I used QThread to update changes in the progress bar as well as running my function. However, the function was not executed. I wonder what is the probelm. I wrote a demo code for that. Hope anyone can help me.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QCheckBox, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QApplication, QHBoxLayout, QLineEdit, QProgressBar
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal
import time
import sys
class CheckToolsGUI(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 400, 250)
        self.setWindowTitle('Application')
        self.run = QPushButton('Run')
        self.run.clicked.connect(self.initialize)
        self.prgb = QProgressBar()
        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.run)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.prgb)
        self.prgb.setMaximum(100)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox)
        
    def initialize(self):
        self.run.setEnabled(False)
        self.test = Test()
        self.test.updateSignal.connect(self.update)
        self.test.updateFinish.connect(self.finish)
        self.test.start()
        
    def update(self,value):
        self.prgb.setValue(value)
        
    def finish(self):
        self.run.setEnable(True)
        
class Test(QThread):
    updateSignal = pyqtSignal(int)
    updateFinish = pyqtSignal()
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print('Start')
    
    def func_1(self):
        print('Func_1')
        for i in range(50):
            self.updateSignal.emit(i)
            time.sleep(0.05)
    def func_2(self):
        print('Func_2')
        for j in range(49,101):
            self.updateSignal.emit(j)
            time.sleep(0.05)
            
    def finish(self):
        self.updateFinish.emit()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = CheckToolsGUI()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I tried as above. I expected the progress bar to be updated but the functions were not even executed.